# What Are The Advantages of Building a Web-Page with Django as Opposed to Solely Using HTML5/CSS3?

Tags: python, html, django, dynamic

Essentially, my questions are as stated above in the title. What I'm really seeking to know is why it would be privy of me to build a web-page utilizing the Django framework as opposed to solely building it out with HTML5 and CSS3.

I do know that Django utilizes bootstrapping of HTML5 and CSS and this is where my questions are raised over the efficiency of using the Django framework as opposed to solely using HTML5/CSS3.

1.) What are the advantages of Django?

2.) What does utilizing the Django framework offer me that HTML5/CSS3 do not?

3.) HTML5 can also build dynamic web-pages as can Django. Why would Django be better for a dynamic web-page?

I am looking for a very valid answer here as I am about to start building my web-page. The responses I get to these questions will be the nail in the coffin for which method I will be using to build the web-page. Thanks ladies and gentleman and I hope you find this question to be worth your while in answering.

Answer (score 3):

1. Django is a server side framework. So it has little to do with HTML.
2. Django will give you easier/standardized ways to handle HTTP requests, and to manipulate entries in the database, among other things.
3. HTML5 alone doesn't enable dynamic web-pages. You can have interactive web pages, but they will always be the same, for every user, whenever you access it.

Comment: If I were to use only HTML then I would be having to rely on what for the HTTP requests? SQL? And would using Django inhibit me from making an extremely intricate website?

Comment: @Dev.Ays a typical LAMP setup can handle HTTP requests - linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP

Comment: Mmk, so to put it metaphorically then, Django allows Python to sit on the server like a soda-machine sits in a fast food joint and, depending on the cup and the preferred drink, dispense that flavor accordingly. With static HTML, it's like bringing a cup to a faucet, and when dispensed, will always dispense water.

Comment: @Dev.Ays, it is more or less like this. If the customers of your fast food joint  (your visitors) would be satisfied with the faucet water (static HTML pages), you could start with it. If in the future you see the need of a soda-machine, you will have more knowledge of your needs, and you would already have the water, that could be used as the base (HTML templates) for your soda-machine to put the flavor on.

Answer (score 1):

Django is a python web *application* framework that allows you to send requests from your page to a server that will in turn provide a response back to your web page.

1. Advantages: The power of Django is the ability to quickly get both the client ( your page ) and the backend ( the server-side logic ) setup.  The backend can include writing to a database, processing information, retrieving information which is subsequently a response delivered to your web page.
2. HTML5/CSS3 is markup languages for your web page.  You can use a editors like sublime or even notepad ++ if you are building a static web page. Django, like most web app frameworks, are used because of what I've described in #1 ( and many other unlisted reasons ).
3. HTML5 provides the ability to make dynamic web pages ( using a client side library like JQuery as an embedded script ), Django helps you build web apps.  You can write a web page using only HTML5 and JQuery to display list of tv shows that are currently on ABC by listing what is currently playing today, but what about for tomorrow?  You need server-side help by creating response that will fetch all shows for tomorrow by calling the ABC API.  Take a look at server-side logic and web applications.

In short, there are web pages and web applications.  Sounds like to me you are building the former, so Django might be overkill.

Answer (score 1):

1.) What are the advantages of Django?

Server-side scripting without the necessity to use PHP. If you already worked with Python, you don't need to learn another language for you server-side.

2.) What does utilizing the Django framework offer me that HTML5/CSS3 do not?

Hm, deployment to a server, handling user requests and dynamically generated webpages. You mentioned making an intricate website in a comment. I don't know what you mean by that, but a framework will let you do this way faster then without. Especially, if you only rely on client-side JS with static HTML5 and CSS3, I'm fairly certain you will have a hard time achieving your goal.

3.) HTML5 can also build dynamic web-pages as can Django. Why would Django be better for a dynamic web-page?

I'm not really sure you understand what dynamic means. Dynamic means generated from code, as opposed to static, which means served directly from an .html file. Django let's you do both, it's a framework and offers lots of flexibility.

Comment: Thank you for this response. Nail in the coffin! This perfectly answers what I am trying to base my decisions on. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to serve same dish for all visitors to your site, HTML is fine. But if you want to server different dish to different user then you'll need ingredients and a way to churn them. Ingredients can be users, their profile and preferences, location, and other entities users are dealing with. Django is one way to churn all of these together and present (in HTML for example) to users.

Comment: Yes, I am starting to see what the capabilities of Django are versus static HTML. For example: Setting a template that is consistent across every page using "include" but varying the other dynamic bits of information as you move from "home" to "about" to "contact"; so on and so forth.

Comment: Setting a template or moving from one page to another can be done in HTML as well. You'll need Django when you deal with interrelated entities  and you need data persistence. For example you can't authenticate your users or track their preferences without using some sort of server side processing and database.